# looping array to another array considering every possibility

Tags: php

what I am trying to do is ...

I have an array called char and a string

```
$char = array("-","_","|","+","~");
$MyString = "this is test string";
```

what I am trying to do is I want to replace every space in $MyString with one char from my array

but I want the result to be like this

[image]

```
$MyString = "this is test string";
$ExplodedString = explode(" ",$MyString);

foreach ($char as $sinchar) {
        $text1 = preg_replace("/ /", $sinchar, $MyString ,1);
       foreach ($char as $sinchar) {
        $text2 = preg_replace("/ /", $sinchar, $text1 ,1);
        //echo $text2."\n";
            foreach ($char as $sinchar) {
                $text3 = preg_replace("/ /", $sinchar, $text2 ,1);
                echo $text3."\n";
            }
       }
}
```

this code works fine for me but its a static code and I am looking for something more dynamic, so if I added a text that has more spaces I don't have to add another loop.

so guys any solutions?

Comment: you have a set of 5 chars, so you at most can have 5 spaces, no?

Comment: not a must , I could have as many chars and 3 spaces and I still should be able to loop all the chars and replace the spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a recursive function, combining permutations for the first word with all possible permutations for the remaining words:

```
function computeAllPermutations(array $words, array $separators): array
{
  switch (count($words)) {
    case 0:
      return [];
    case 1:
      return [$words[0]];
    default:
      $permutations = [];
      foreach (computeAllPermutations(array_slice($words, 1), $separators) as $subPermutation) {
        foreach ($separators as $separator) {
          $permutations[] = $words[0] . $separator . $subPermutation;
        }
      }
      return $permutations;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
$words = preg_split('/\h+/', $MyString);
$permutations = computeAllPermutations($words, $char);
print_r($permutations);
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/uKtYC)